# Validar se a pessoa e maior de idade

Tags: javascript, jquery-validation-engine

Boa tarde pessoal, como verifico se uma pessoa é maior de idade com o plugin `jQuery.validationEngine`?

Preciso que o `form` só valide se a pessoa possuir mais de 18 anos, se for menor de 18 anos ela é bloqueada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma função que vai determinar a sua validação:

```
function checkIdade(field, rules, i, options){
  if (field.val() < 18) {
     // this allows the use of i18 for the error msgs
     return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
  }
}
```

depois chame no seu input na `class="validate[required,funcCall[checkIdade]]"`

```
<input class="validate[required,funcCall[checkIdade]]" 
       type="text" 
       id="idade" 
       name="idade" />
```

[funcCall[methodName]](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#funccallmethodname)

```js
function checkIdade(field, rules, i, options) {
  if (field.val() < 18) {
    return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form1").validationEngine();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/jquery.validationEngine.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/validationEngine.jquery.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<form action="" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">
  <input type="text" id="idade" name="idade" class="validate[required,funcCall[checkIdade]]">
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```